# how to pack python code with pyarmor and virtual environment?

Tags: python, pyarmor

I have a python project consisting of multiple files I try to pack it with pyarmor and it is working fine however when I try to pack it with a virtual environment I face a lot of errors so if anyone knows how to do it please help.

I add the required packages in the venv even pyarmor then I activate it and when pyarmor finish obfuscation
it told me that "run command failed".

Answer (score 0):

Will i figure out how to do it the issue is that i already install Anaconda so i creat the virtual environment through conda in the cmd.

I follow the instructions @ https://youtu.be/mIB7IZFCE_k